# Issues with adding new array in update

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

The update for my app is now ready, however I have noticed that updating directly from the version of my app that is on the app store, to the new version that I am working on in Xcode seems to crash my app.

Basically, I added a new array that stores data for notes which was not present in previous versions and this is stored in NSUserDefaults (Not ideal, I know, but I would rather keep it this way for now)

When I go into the table view tab of my app, it crashes at this line:

```
cell.notesLabel.text = (notes.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
```

The error just states - "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" as soon as the table view tab is tapped.

I was discussing this with someone else and they suggested that I need to check for the existence of the array in the defaults and create and synchronise it if it is missing.

I'm not entirely sure how I would go about this, but I have tried changing my code from this:

```
if var tempNotes: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes") {
    notes = tempNotes.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
}
```

To this:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes") != nil {
    var tempNotes: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes")!
    notes = tempNotes.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
}
```

However it doesn't seem to have made a difference. That code is in viewWillAppear() by the way.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` and `numberOfRowsInSection()` code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
    if names.count == 0 {
        if enterButtonTapped == false {
            backgroundLabel.text = "Before you add any transactions, you must first set a budget. You can do this by tapping the 'Budget' tab."
        } else {
            backgroundLabel.text = "You haven't added any transactions yet. Tap the add button to add a new transaction."
        }
        backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        backgroundLabel.sizeToFit()
        backgroundLabel.hidden = false
        backgroundLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17)
        backgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        clearButton.enabled = false

        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        return 0
    } else {
        backgroundLabel.hidden = true
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
        clearButton.enabled = true
        return names.count
    }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:CustomTransactionTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell

    var arrowX: CGFloat = 0
    var amountX: CGFloat = 0
    if height == 480 || height == 568 {
        arrowX = 260
        amountX = 152
    } else if height == 667 {
        arrowX = 315
        amountX = 217
    } else {
        arrowX = 354
        amountX = 217
    }

    cell.notesLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.paymentNameLabel.frame.origin.x = 20
    cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x = 20
    cell.costLabel.frame.origin.x = amountX
    cell.creditArrowImage.frame.origin.x = arrowX
    cell.paymentArrowImage.frame.origin.x = arrowX

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        var indexValue = names.indexOfObject(searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))
        cell.costLabel.text = (values.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as? String
        cell.dateLabel.text = (dates.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as? String
        cell.notesLabel.text = (notes.objectAtIndex(indexValue)) as? String

        if images.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSObject == 0 {
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
        } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSObject == 1 {
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
        }

        if notes.objectAtIndex(indexValue) as NSString == "" {
            cell.notesLabel.text = "No notes to display."
        }

        //This works, unless there are two payments with the same name. To revert to previous version, remove tableView if statement and just keep code below the else.
    } else {
        cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (names.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        cell.costLabel.text = (values.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        cell.dateLabel.text = (dates.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
        cell.notesLabel.text = (notes.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String

        if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = true
        } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
            cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
            cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = true
        }

        if notes.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSString == "" {
            cell.notesLabel.text = "No notes to display."
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please post the datasource numberOfRowsInSection.  Also, set an exception breakpoint so you can be sure of which line is causing the crash.

Comment: I've updated my question with numberOfRowsInSection and didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I've got an exception breakpoint set up and it's definitely the line that I stated that is causing the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick skim reveals that there's complex logic deciding how many rows to return in numberOfRows, and then complex --and different-- logic to access arrays based on the indexPath in cellForRow.  Before we even get to the user defaults issue - the code is a recipe for crash.  The proper form of the two methods is to put them in tight correspondence with each other:

- In numbeOfRows, decide which array you're going to answer the count
  for.  That's your model.
- In cellForRow, dereference *that same array*
  with indexPath.row.  You'll never have an index out of bounds this
  way, because if you answer N for numberOfRows (where
  N=someArray.count), then cellForRow will only be called with rows
  0..N-1

On the user defaults issue:  Your new app version must be prepared to handle any state of user defaults left by your old version, including absence, for users who never owned your old version.  To bullet-proof yourself, always get the array in defaults via a method.  It should look for the array in defaults.  If found, cache a mutable copy as an instance variable and return it.  Otherwise, if **not found** (the code you posted tests `arrayForKey("notes") != nil` which is the opposite of not found), initialize your instance var to a new array and return that.